# Parsing string that is actually an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am parsing an ajax request whose return value is

`"[ { message: 'Rate limit exceeded', code: 88 } ]"`

Because the value is a string, I'm not able extra the code value from the object - for example, I would want to do something like `response.code` to get 88.  Any ideas?

Comment: The API you're working with looks broken - if you can fix it so it returns proper JSON, you can then `parse` it and get the info easily

Comment: maybe you could try `JSON.parse(response);`?

Comment: Where/How is this string generated?

Answer (score 1):

`"[ { message: 'Rate limit exceeded', code: 88 } ]"` is not a valid JSON string. You have to do the correction in the API so that the response is provided like:

```
'[ {"message": "Rate limit exceeded", "code": 88 } ]'
```

Then you can use `JSON.parse()`.

```js
var response = '[ {"message": "Rate limit exceeded", "code": 88 } ]';
response = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(response[0].code);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try parse this data like this

```
var obj = "[ { message: 'Rate limit exceeded', code: 88 } ]";
var myJSON = JSON.parse(obj);
```

You will get error as `"Unexpected token m in JSON at position 4"`

Your JSON is not in correct format. Something like this will work

```
var obj = '[{"message": "Rate limit exceeded", "code": 88}]';
var myJSON = JSON.parse(obj);

alert(myJSON[0].code); // will print 88
```